# Optional/ignored argument in C++ lambda, or lambda signature-based overload resolution

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have an iteration helper like this:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename Op>
void for_each(T* a, size_t n, Op op) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = op(a[i], i);
    }
}
```

I'd like it to be able usable with or without the `i` argument to `op`:

```cpp
// float* a;
for_each(a, n, [](const float& v) { return v + 1; });
for_each(a, n, [](const float& v, const size_t& i) { return v + i; });
```

Is there a way to do this with C++14 or earlier?

Note: I don't have the option of using `(const float& v, size_t) { }` to ignore the second arg, nor the option of changing the `op` signature to `std::pair<T, size_t>` or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With SFINAE, you might do

```
template <typename T, typename Op>
auto for_each(T* a, size_t n, Op op) -> decltype(op(a[n], n), void()){
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = op(a[i], i);
    }
}
template <typename T, typename Op>
auto for_each(T* a, size_t n, Op op) -> decltype(op(a[n]), void()){
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = op(a[i]);
    }
}
```